# Trasnformar array em divs?

Tags: php, sql, array

Tenho uma página `php` que me trás uma lista de cadastro, porém ele trás uma `array` e gostaria que cada item dele viesse em `divs` ou tabela com linhas.

Abaixo o que estou fazendo:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('user_id');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__tabela'));          
$db->setQuery($query);
$column= $db->loadColumn();
print_r($column);
```

Ele me retorna:

> `Array ( [0] => 703 [1] => 704 [2] => 719 [3] => 716 [4] => 719 [5] =>
>   722 [6] => 724 [7] => 725 [8] => 729 [9] => 730 [10] => 732 [11] =>
>   733 [12] => 735 [13] => 736 [14] => 737 [15] => 744 )`

Gostaria que viesse algo assim:

```
<tr>703</tr>
<tr>704</tr>
<tr>719</tr>
...
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Basta fazer um `foreach` e então adicionar o `tr`:

```
foreach($column as $value){
    echo '<tr>' . $value . '</tr>';
}
```

[Teste isto aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74ea92aea0ff7f7ebac3d62b150035f09dfb58c9)

Isso vai exibir o valor entre `tr`.

---

Entretanto se você deseja um array com o "prefixo" e "sufixo" de `<tr>` e `</tr>` você pode usar o `array_map`:

```
$array = array_map(function($value) { return '<tr>'.$value.'</tr>'; }, $column);
```

Dessa forma usando um:

```
var_dump($array);
```

Você terá:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "<tr>703</tr>"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "<tr>704</tr>"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "<tr>719</tr>"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "<tr>716</tr>"
  [4]=>
  string(12) "<tr>719</tr>"
  [5]=>
  string(12) "<tr>722</tr>"
}
```

[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ced6c6d03c8e2a41b554b2e9ff66dd2d5772191a)

---

Uma outra opção, se está utilizando MySQL, é utilizar o`CONCAT`, dessa forma poderá fazer:

```
SELECT CONCAT('<tr>', Coluna, '</tr>') as Coluna FROM tabela
```

Isso já irá retornar os dados da "Coluna" entre os `tr`, sem necessidade de tratamento por PHP.

Comment: o que quero é um em cada tr mesmo, esse do SELECT CONCAT como uso? 
vlw!!

Comment: ele retornou tudo em sequência usando o foreach:
703704719716719722724725729730732733735736737744

Comment: Provavelmente porque foi renderizado pelo navegador, dê um F12 ou CTRL+U, e verifique que irá existir os `tr`.